# Pandas returning whole dataframe when .loc to a specific column that is not existant

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names `['2533,3093', '1645,2421', '1776,1645', '3133,2533', '2295,2870']` and I'm trying to add a new column which is `'2009,3093'`.

I'm using `df.loc[:, col] = some series`, but it is returning a KeyError meaning that column does not exist. But by default, pandas would create that column. If I do `df.loc[:, 'test'] = value` it works fine.

But somehow, when I do `df.loc[:, col]`, it returns me the entire dataframe. When it should actually return a KeyError, because the column does not existe in the dataframe.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please use this syntax

```
df.loc[:,[column name]] = series

df.loc[:, ['2009,3093']] = series
```

I have used this code for testing, not sure what series you were trying to assing

```
import pandas as pd
col = ['2533,3093', '1645,2421', '1776,1645', '3133,2533']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
df.loc[:, ['2009,3093']] = ['a','b','c','d']
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes dataframe insert is what you need here [pandas.DataFrame.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

Comment: It is because I'm adding the location index.  I just did not mention it because I thought it did not matter (and still do). I am using .loc[idx, col]. 

It works fine with any other column name. Even if no index is specified. You could do df.loc[:, 'test'] = float('nan') and it would just create a blank column.

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: That does not work. Loc does not create columns when passing list-like.

Comment: can you update the series what you are trying to assign ?